# What is majorization, and how is it related to Muirhead's inequalities?

Tags: inequality, muirhead-inequality, majorization

I was reading the following article: http://math.rice.edu/MathCircle/References/0%20Mildorf%20Inequalities%202%20-%20LECTURE.pdf

As I'm not too experienced with problem solving in inequalities, I have a few questions about this.

1. What is majorization? I don't really understand this - especially the application to Muirhead's inequality.
2. What does $\sum_{sym}$ mean? How does Muirhead's inequality work? Could I have an example, please?

Comment: Note that Muirhead is generally regarded as "not rigorous," but is mainly used for intuition.

Comment: Why not? It's a perfect valid inequality, is it not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The definition of marjorization is straightforward. For two vectors $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ with non-increasing terms, then $\mathbf{x}$ is said to majorize $\mathbf{y}$ if
   $$
   \sum_{j=1}^k x_j \geq \sum_{j=1}^k y_j  \qquad (k=1,2,\dots,n).
   $$
   As an example, $(3,2,1)$ is majorized by $(4,2,1)$ since
   $$4>3, \qquad 4+2>3+2 \qquad\text{and}\qquad 4+2+1>3+2+1.$$
   Additionally, $(3,2,1)$ is majorized by $(5,2,0)$ but not by $(3,0,0)$. If you want to compare two vectors whose elements may not be non-increasing, first you sort them. For further details see the technical report [Inequalities via Majorization](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~ckirby/techreports/NSF/OLK%20NSF%20172.pdf), which appears to be notes leading to [this book](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-0-387-40087-7). There's also a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization).
2. Let's look at an example of the operator $\sum_{\text{sym}}$ when applied to the monomial $x^2y^3z^5$. We expand using the permutations of the set of exponents $\{2,3,5\}$. This results in six terms:
   $$
   \sum_{\text{sym}} x^2y^3z^5 = x^2y^3z^5 + x^2y^5z^3 + x^3y^2z^5 \\ + x^5y^3z^2 + x^5y^2z^3 + x^3y^5z^2.
   $$
   The [Wikipedia article on Muirhead's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality#Examples) has two basic applications. For instance, to prove $x^2+y^2 \geq 2xy$, write it as
   $$
   \color{blue}{x^2+y^2=} \sum_{\text{sym}} x^2y^0 \geq \sum_{\text{sym}} x^1y^1 \color{blue}{=xy+xy}
   $$
   and observe that $(2,0)$ majorizes $(1,1)$. Note here that we consider the repeated exponents on the right hand side as distinct.

Comment: Thank you! I assume $\sum_{cyc}$ would work similarly?

Comment: @Ayesha Maybe, it depends on how the notation is defined.

Comment: the last relation of majorization is an equality i.e. $x_1+\cdots+x_n=y_1+\cdots+y_n$.